# Twig evaluate variable within variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

New to twig and haven't found a great answer so far on this one:

I have an associative array of TimberMenus in the Timber context and each one corresponds to a different WordPress menu via the menu id.

In the Twig file I want a dynamic check to select which menu should be displayed, and evaluate the `menu_name` variable.

```
{% if menus.{{menu_name}}.items %}
```

So if `menu_name` = 'academics', I'd like the above code to evaluate to:

```
 {% if menus.academics.items %}
```

The above doesn't work and I can't seem to find how I would accomplish this within Twig.

Any ideas or help very welcome!

Comment: have you tried with `menus.[menu_name].items`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the [variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) section you can use the "subscript" syntax ([]), as example:

```
{%set menu_name = 'academics'%}

{{menus[menu_name].items}}
```

Check [this](https://twigfiddle.com/k10xa8) working example

Hope this help

Comment: or use the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function

Comment: Hi @Cnote if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, Thank YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

There is [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function, that allow to access dynamic properties:

```
{% if attribute(menus, menu_name).items %}
```